AWS DynamoDB download speed with Boto3
I am using python/Boto3 to download logs from a health tracking device. I wrote a python app that lets you run a paginated query for a a given user & timeframe:

def paginated_query(self, tstart, tend, user):
        paginator = self.datapoints_table.meta.client.get_paginator('query')
        page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
            TableName=self.table_name,
            KeyConditionExpression= Key('userId').eq(user_id) & Key('timestamp').between(tstart, tend)
            )


The query itself works and executes within a few milliseconds.
Then, to download the data and process it with python, I convert the generator into a list:
page_iterator = self.paginated_query(tstart, tend, user)

log_list = []
for p in page_iterator:
    items = p.get('Items', []) # download the data
    log_list.extend(items) 

This last snippet takes a very long time depending on how much data I am trying to download.
I tried to process pages in parallel, instead of sequentially in a for loop, but it makes no difference in the execution time.
I measured a data download rate from DynamoDB/AWS at 1.8MB/s max, which seems much slower than what my connection could achieve. I can only assume there is a bottleneck on AWS side.
Does anyone know how to make the data download faster?

I cannot see why you're being limited to 1.8 MB/s, that's just two pages per second. You should be able to obtain 36 MB/s without causing throttling on your key. I would suggest splitting your range and running a parallel query for each range. Something like below (not tested):
import aioboto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
import asyncio
import datetime

async def paginated_query_async(table_name, tstart, tend, user_id, interval_minutes=5):

    interval = datetime.timedelta(minutes=interval_minutes)
    
    time_ranges = []
    current_start = tstart
    while current_start < tend:
        current_end = min(current_start + interval, tend)
        time_ranges.append((current_start, current_end))
        current_start = current_end

    async with aioboto3.resource('dynamodb') as dynamodb:
        table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)

        async def query_range(start, end):
            paginator = table.meta.client.get_paginator('query')
            page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
                TableName=table_name,
                KeyConditionExpression=Key('userId').eq(user_id) & Key('timestamp').between(start, end)
            )
            results = []
            async for page in page_iterator:
                items = page.get('Items', [])
                results.extend(items)
            return results

        tasks = [query_range(start, end) for start, end in time_ranges]
        all_results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        log_list = [item for sublist in all_results for item in sublist]
        
    return log_list

async def main():
    tstart = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0)
    tend = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 23, 59)
    user_id = "user123"
    table_name = "<TableName>"
    
    log_list = await paginated_query_async(table_name, tstart, tend, user_id)
    print(log_list)


asyncio.run(main())


I tried the code above and added some timing with ttictoc. I do get a slight performance improvement, with an average of 16 items/second, vs 10 items/second using my previous code.
Using sys.getsizeof(log_list) / elapsed time, it suggests I am actually closer to 150 bytes/sec, which seems in line with how slow things are.
The 1.8MB/s was from windows resource monitor (network tab, looking at python's received B/s). The new code shows 3 MB/s

are you seeing throttled in your DynamoDB metrics?

Thanks for your help Leeroy. Yes, I seem to have some Throttling events:
Metric: ConsumedReadCapacityUnits 2024-10-25 15:50:00+00:00: 18957.5 throttling events
Can you help me resolve this?

That's your bottleneck. Increase your capacity to prevent throttling.

The read capacity mode is "On-demand". Should I change to a Provisioned plan?
The dashboard says  my current table throughput quota is 40,000 read request units/second

If it's on-demand then you're fine with capacity. I suspect you're making too many requests to the same partition key. Each partition key can give you 3000RCU per second.

Thanks a lot for your help @Leeroy Hannigan. I guess it's time to reconsider the database structure a little bit.
